# git fatal: could not create work tree dir 'projectexpat': Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, digital, ocean

What do I do now? I am trying to deploy a laravel app through digital ocean and it is sucking my will to live.

Comment: you should specify more of the situation, and it is a repeated question, try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276895/could-not-create-work-tree-dir-example-com-permission-denied

Comment: Permission denied typically means the credentials/JWT/authentication used are not authorized to take the action shown.  The credential you are using may have read-only permissions, but this error message looks a write attempt.   Should your "deployment" really be trying to create a new directory in git?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fatal: could not create work tree dir 'kivy'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376035/fatal-could-not-create-work-tree-dir-kivy)

Answer (score 1):

Change Your project ower:
sudo chown -R **yourusername** /var/www